# 'sh.exe": ionic: command not found on windows 8

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am at the end of ionic app development & about to finish my first ionic based mobile app. I have my app developed in cordova with ionic framework & angularJS. Through git bash when i entered following command after long time of Idle work i got the above error.

Command

```
ionic build android
```

Here it is showing me the above error that i haven't even seen before when i was developing app & building it for testing. Thing is after one month of non working phase on ionic application, when today i opened Git Bash & tried building APK after long time then it is showing me the error what could possibly happened here?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have `ionic` installed, or you do not have it in your search path. Add the directory of ionic to the `PATH` variable to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Well i got it. I have not updated the ionic version after long time of non working phase. When i updated the version it built my app.

Comment: where exactly should I go to update the ionic version ?? is there a specific command to do that ??